# Practical Implementation for Refinement Order on Integer Partitions

Tags: algorithms, integers, integer-partitions

The refinement order on partitions of an integer $n$ can be defined as follows: $\lambda=(\lambda_1,\dots,\lambda_k)\leq\mu=(\mu_1,\dots,\mu_\ell)$ if there is a partition of the parts of $\lambda$ into blocks whose sums are the parts of $\mu$.

It is known that the problem of deciding whether $\lambda\leq\mu$ is NP-complete.  However, for a practical application I would need an algorithm which performs reasonably when $n$ is around $200$.  Ideally, this algorithm would already have a (free) implementation...

I tried the following naive approach:

- find the last index $j$ such that $\mu_j>\lambda_1$
- if $\mu_{j+1} = \lambda_1$ remove $\mu_{j+1}$ from $\mu$ and $\lambda_1$ from $\lambda$ and recurse
- otherwise, for $j\in\{j,j-1,\dots,1\}$:

  - subtract $\lambda_1$ from $\mu_j$ and reorder to obtain a new partition, and recurse with this partition and the rest of $\lambda$

Although this seems to work reasonably well for many pairs $(\lambda,\mu)$ of partitions of size around $200$, it performs poorly when $\lambda$ has many small parts but is not a refinement of $\mu$.

Comment: Why do you expect such an algorithm to exist?

Comment: @YuvalFilmus: I am only hoping for it, because I would like to use it.  Perhaps I do have some hope because even the simple approach I outlined above seems to perform very badly only in very few cases.  I'd also be interested in any experiments other people did.

Comment: [A couple approaches in Sage](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1798383/integer-partition-refinement-in-sage) have shown up on Math.SE.

Answer (score 3):

I suggest you try using integer linear programming.  Introduce $k\ell$ zero-or-one variables $x_{i,j}$, with the constraints

$$\sum_j x_{i,j} \lambda_j = \mu_i$$

and

$$\sum_i x_{i,j} = 1.$$

Feed it to an off-the-shelf ILP solver.  If it can find a feasible solution for you, then you know that $\lambda \le \mu$.  If it can determine that no solution exists, then you know that $\lambda \not\le \mu$.

Comment: Admittedly a very "soft" question: should I expect that a specialised approach (whatever that would be) performs in the worst case just as badly as this approach?

Comment: I did a test, indeed it seems that linear programming (I used cplex) is better in the worst case.  I ran (a slightly refined) version of the algorithm in the question for 1000 random partitions of 100, and got a worst case timing of 320 seconds, whereas MILP's worst case was around 0.1 seconds.

Comment: My comment above has bad numbers, but seems to be essentially correct.  (I found a partition of 200 where "my" algorithm takes around 20 seconds, but nothing like that for cplex.) Sorry for the noise.

Comment: Unfortunately, it seems that only cplex does the job quickly.  I tried GLPK and CBC now, and they are both unusable for the problem, it appears...

Comment: Sorry, with "linear programming" I meant "integer linear programming".  The "only" remaining problem is that I probably can't use cplex for the real thing (a website), and GLPK and CBC are not up to the task...